# Can Veneti and Antuerpiae be vocatives?

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation, new-latin

I am puzzling over:

> caveat veneti et antuerpiae exemplo tiri et tu lundina

This was written in the margin of a sixteenth-century commentary on Isaiah at chapter 23, which is on Tyre.

My translation is:

> Beware, O Venice and Antwerp of the example of Tyre, and thou, too, O London.

Can *Veneti* and *Antuerpiae* be vocatives?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I was writing an answer, but then became puzzled too. Veneti _can_ be the vocative of both the Venetic and Venetians (but then the verb should be caveant). In oder to be a vocative, in turn, antuerpiae should refer to the city, not the people. Antwerp is spelled antuerpia, the demonyn seems to be antuerpiensis. I don't know whether antuerpiae is also a valid spelling, but it could be a plural as well–yet also a locative, genitive, etc. The word _to_ also puzzles me. Is the marginal note XVI century? Can we know how fluent in Latin the writer was/where was he from?

Comment: The "to" that you mention is probably "tu". I corrected the typo. The marginal note is XVI century. I don't know how fluent in Latin the writer was, but the commentary that he was reading was in Latin. The writer was a Scot, but possibly living in London.

Comment: Do you have a photo of the actual text? That could help think of alternative readings; with just the transcription it's hard to tell whether the first word could be *caveas* instead, for example. Something seems to be a little awry, and it's hard to guess what.

Comment: I don't have a photo, I am afraid. I just took the text from an article. There may be a typo in the article. The book itself is in the John Rylands Library.

Comment: Do you have a link to the article? Perhaps there are transcription errors. Perhaps there was a short stroke above the a in *caveat*, which would indicate an *n*.

Comment: @Rafael There is some indication that Antwerp in Latin may sometimes have been "Antuerpiae".  It's notable that the Dutch and French names for Antwerp both look like plurals in form (of course, this doesn't prove anything in itself, but fwiw, Antwerpen and Anvers respectively) (as does the Spanish Amberes). See https://rbms.info/lpn/a/antuerpiae/

Comment: Stupid question, perhaps, but isn't 'London' Londinium in Latin? Or does that change to Lundina over the centuries?

Comment: @cnread Wiktionary includes "Lundonia" as a medieval name for London, but even more relevantly, a book of illustrations of London was published in the early 19c under the title "Londina Illustrata" ( https://www.royalacademy.org.uk/art-artists/book/londina-illustrata-graphic-and-historic-memorials-of-monasteries-churches )

Comment: @Cerberus This is the article for those that have access to it. The reference is on p. 33.  https://doi.org/10.7227/BJRL.96.1.2 The translation given in the article is "Be wary of the example of Venice and Antwerp as well as Tyre and London".

Comment: @user558840: Sci-Hub won't let me see the article. Perhaps you might consider posting the relevant passage and some text around it in the question; more context may help.

Comment: @BrynJess Thanks for the edit! I made some further adjustments because [we are getting rid of the tag "translation"](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/347/79).

Comment: The *Orbis Latinus* only gives singular Latin names for Antwerp: http://www.columbia.edu/acis/ets/Graesse/orblata.html But it could still be intended as plural by this particular author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It strikes as not only possible, but likely. I don't see a reason to disregard *Antwerpiae* as a possible nominative/vocative (the name of the city in Flemish is *Antwerpen*, which even to a native speaker today sounds similar to a plural and plural forms for city names are, of course, as old/common as anything, e.g. the obviously analogy with *Athenae*).

Comment: Welcome to the site! The *Orbis Latinus* only seems to give singular Latin names for Antwerp:
http://www.columbia.edu/acis/ets/Graesse/orblata.html
But it is nevertheless possible that the author treated it as plural, especially when adjacent to *Veneti*, which is clearly plural.

Comment: Many thanks. Since you alone have dignified your comment with the title 'Answer' I shall award you the prize. Who dares, wins!